# NSOperation with dependency not being executed when added to NSOperationQueue

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios5, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I'm trying to figure out why a NSOperation with a dependency is not being executed when added to NSOperationQueue (iOS5, ARC):

```
@implementation NSOperationTest {
    NSOperationQueue *_operationQueue;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) test
{
    NSBlockOperation *op1 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"op1 running");
    }];

    NSBlockOperation *op2 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"op2 running");
    }];

    [op2 addDependency:op1];
    [_operationQueue addOperation:op2];
}
@end
```

This is getting me crazy, here `op1` is supposed to be executed before `op2`, but either is executed, when added without dependencies both works just fine. Does someone knows why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You have to explicitly any operation to the operation queue (or execute it directly) in order for it to execute - and dependencies are no exception. Without doing so (as you've done) `op2` will never execute because it is waiting for `op1` to execute, when `op1` has never been told to execute. So by adding `[_operationQueue addOperation: op1];` at the end of your `test` method, your problem should be fixed.